# How to provide a calculated timestamp to GStreamer's timeoverlay?

Tags: c, gstreamer, embedded-linux, gstreamer-1.0

I have a pipeline I intend on using in a C/C++ application, and the system that the application is running on is in UTC.  I would like to have the pipeline display the timestamp in the local time, based on IP location, likely using a Geolocator that provides the timezone in the response (e.g. https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip).

I thought maybe I could just change the timezone of the application, but calling `tzset` just changes the label from UTC without converting the time to the correct value. I also don't see any properties on `clockoverlay` that would fit.

Another general concern is making sure that the time conversion doesn't lead to inaccurate timestamps due to computation time, but depending on any possible implementations, I'm hoping this isn't an issue.